# How to determine on which column the onFilterDropdownOpenChange was fired?

Tags: reactjs, antd

In ANT 4.23.0, a new API callback function was added on the Table Column: `onFilterDropdownOpenChange`. This callback takes in one parameter, a boolean that is either true or false depending on whether the filterDropdown is opening/closing. All of this according to the docs:

```
onFilterDropdownOpenChange Callback executed when filterDropdownOpen is changed
```

I want to implement this callback function on multiple columns in my Table to keep track of the filterDropdown that is currently open, but the callback doesn't seem to give any information about the column itself.

I need this information (for example the column *key or dataindex*) to save in a state variable, so I can always know the correct column that has the FilterDropdown open.

So is it possible to find out the *key/dataIndex* of the column where the `onFilterDropdownOpenChange` is being fired?

I checked if the parameter that is passed to the function contains any information about the column, but this is just a boolean value. I checked if more parameters could be passed but this is not the case. So the code is just this:

```
{
    dataIndex: 'id',
    key: 'id',
    onFilterDropdownOpenChange: (open: boolean) => {
      console.log(open);
      // can I know the dataIndex or key here?
    },
}
```

Comment: No. you cannot get the key for that column. If i'm not wrong, you want to have one function that controls the state of each column filter. If that so, you can solve this by map over the columns array and call that common function with `open` value and the key of that column.  `[].map((column) => ({ ...column, onFilterDropdownOpenChange: (open) => onFilterDropdownOpenChange(open, column.key) }))`

Comment: Thank you for your comment, this actually works. Should I add this as the answer below?

Comment: Jef Ceuppens Sure.

Answer (score 0):

Answer provided by Muhammad Nouman Rafique

No. you cannot get the key for that column. If i'm not wrong, you want to have one function that controls the state of each column filter. If that is so, you can solve this by mapping over the columns array and call that common function with open value and the key of that column.

```
columns.map((column) => ({ ...column, onFilterDropdownOpenChange: (open) => onFilterDropdownOpenChangeHandler(open, column.key) }))
```